# Student Resident permit

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, long-stay-visas, finland

I am applying for student resident card for a university in Finland.

Before reaching Finland for my studies, I first plan to visit Germany.

Is it okay to first travel to Germany and then proceed for Finland on the same student resident permit?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=de&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=fi&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines (destination Germany, with a random nationality entered for search purposes, but it applies to all non-EU/EFTA citizens):

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a residence permit issued by Finland for a maximum stay of 90 days.

So yes, you can enter Germany on your Finnish residence permit, and in fact there will be no border control when flying from Germany to Finland (it will be like a domestic flight). So do have the documents relevant to your studies ready for presentation to the Germans.